# How to GROUP BY in T-SQL in this case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to show the total number of hours imputed by each employee in a project in SAP Business One

[image: select]

But as a durtype in some cases it is m (minutes) and others h (hours) I get 2 rows for employee 373

Someone can think of how I can solve this without having a SELECT above to group by empid for example

Regards

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2029983)

Comment: Post the query and text, not the image. Images can't be googled, run, tested. Don't force people to type all this to help you

Comment: Sorry,but my first option was to paste the code but in my browser I had many troubles tabulating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one `SUM()` & Remove  `durtype` from `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT . . . , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN durtype = 'M' THEN duration / 60 ELSE duration END) AS NumberOfHoursMade
FROM . . . 
WHERE . . .
GROUP BY . . . ;
```